# Atomic `ln -sf` in python (symlink overwriting exsting file)

Tags: python, atomic, symlink

I want create a symlink, overwriting an existing file or symlink if needed.

I've discovered that [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) only returns `True` for non-broken symlinks, so I'm guessing that any test must also include [`os.path.lexists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.lexists).

What is the most atomic way to implement `ln -sf` in python? (Ie, preventing a file being created by another process between deletion and symlink creation)

---

Differentiation: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8299386/5353461) doesn't specify the atomic requirement

Comment: If you prepare `ln -s file tmplink`, then `mv tmplink link` is atomic.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for the suggestion. I still see a security hole, but I hope I got it as good as possible in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741590/5353461).

Comment: FWIW, `ln -sf` itself **is not actually atomic**. GNU Coreutils [internally implements](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/force-link.c?h=v8.32#n143) the solution that @Amadan proposed (and that the currently-accepted answer implements); FreeBSD and Busybox simply *delete the destination file* before linking. So "par" is actually pretty easy to clear for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tries to minimise the possibilities for race conditions:

```
import os
import tempfile

def symlink_force(target, link_name):
    '''
    Create a symbolic link link_name pointing to target.
    Overwrites link_name if it exists.
    '''

    # os.replace() may fail if files are on different filesystems
    link_dir = os.path.dirname(link_name)

    while True:
        temp_link_name = tempfile.mktemp(dir=link_dir)
        try:
            os.symlink(target, temp_link_name)
            break
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
    try:
        os.replace(temp_link_name, link_name)
    except OSError:  # e.g. permission denied
        os.remove(temp_link_name)
        raise
```

Note:

1. If the function is interrupted (e.g. computer crashes), an additional random link to the target might exist.
2. An unlikely race condition still remains: the symlink created at the randomly-named `temp_link_name` could be modified by another process before replacing `link_name`.

I raised a [python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36656) to highlight the issues of `os.symlink()` requiring the target not exist.

Credit to [Robert Seimer's input](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55742015/3).

Comment: I raised an [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36656) for the security hole mentioned above.

Comment: You could handle the (unlikely) race by putting the `mktemp`+`symlink` calls inside a loop, retrying until you win the race.  Obviously you would need to check that `symlink` failed because of `EEXIST` and not for some other reason that's never going to let it succeed.  And for efficiency you'd probably want to hoist the embedded `dirname` call above the loop.

Comment: @ottomeister Thanks, your suggestion helps. But how to prevent the `mktemp`-named file being changed after creation and before replacing the symlink?

Comment: You can't prevent that.  Any badly-behaved process that has write access to this directory can destroy the whole arrangement.  It's just as possible that something could replace or delete the new symlink _after_ the rename, as it is that something could replace or delete it _before_ the rename.  But if you're worried about concurrent `mktemp`s accidentally colliding on the same name then you could `mkdtemp` a directory, create the new symlink in that directory, then `rename` the symlink over the original one (and then `rmdir` the temp directory).  A `rename` within a filesystem is atomic.

Comment: I am somewhat astounded that this didn't come OOTB.